# Is there a (long-distance-) trail without any available maps?

Tags: hiking, trekking, maps

I'm a cartographer specialized in trekking/hiking maps in scale from 1:75.000 to 1:25.000 for regions without any accessible base maps. 
Now, I'm looking for new work for the next projects :) Perhaps anyone here is missing a map for a certain hiking trail?

Comment: Where is a reasonable work area for you?  Are you expecting to get paid for this?

Comment: Yes I do. I have to make a living :-)

Comment: Then you should make it clear you are soliciting your services.  I shouldn't have to ask to find this out.  It puts your offer into a whole different light, and makes a huge difference, as there is little or no budget for the vast majority of trails.  It also helps, especially when representing yourself professionally, to actually answer the questions that were asked.  Your behavior here has so far been rather off-putting.  Of course a professional needs to make a living, but the question was whether this was a professional or volunteer offer, so your answer is a bit rude.

Comment: I hope there is, because it is sad to think that everything has been mapped.....if you map it there will be one less unknown place, but I wish you well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a solicitation.

Comment: I am voting to leave it open. He isn't advertising his company/freelancing/name, he just asks for regions which are unmapped. If it's worth the work he has to decide. And he is not trying to make money here, just asking for information. The given information will be available for the whole web, so what's the problem?

Comment: Right, Wills! I'm just looking for ideas  - I'm unfotunatly not able to travel around to visit every mountain range or hiking trail. My size of view is much smaler then yours. So thanks for any Ideas!

Comment: Hmm.. I'll refrain from voting for the moment. The question does sound like a solicitation to me but it _can_ be answered otherwise.

Comment: This is also pretty much a list question with no definable single answer

Comment: I disagree with this question being about solicitation. MAP is attempting to use this site as a resource to shortcut his research. While I don't like it, that doesn't make this a bad question. What gets me to agree with the closure is Liam's point about it being a list question.

Comment: Suppose a user asked:  "I am looking for a long trail that doesn't have much traffic --  the Appalachian, the Pacific Crest and the John Muir just don't let me get away from it all.  Suggestions?"   We'd probably ask for some more info -- how long do you have, do you have a geographical preference -- but we wouldn't close it as a "list question".   Don't answer the Q if you don't like it, but I, for one, am curious as to what might come up.

Comment: Haven't been on here in quite some time but this piqued my interest. I vote to keep, on the grounds that it has potential to be a very interesting, answerable question, but it needs to be completely reworded to be both more answerable and a with a disclaimer of solicitation... @MAP

Comment: It's now been two days and the OP hasn't corrected or clarified the question at all, even though he was here only 5 hours ago.  This could have been a good question, but is not in its current form.  Since the OP is refusing to cooperate, it's time to close this failure and move on.

Comment: Another problem: a commercial map-maker will want to focus on popular areas, but in popular areas following the trail is easy even with a large-scale map.  Following a rarely trodden trail, maps are essential, but such maps can never be profitable.  Hence, I always end up relying on maps produced with public data such as collected by topographic institutes.

Answer (score 11):

Of course, there are ***many*** long-distance hiking trails without any available maps.

As far as I'm aware, **none** of the [European long-distance trails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_long-distance_paths) have dedicated end-to-end maps, unless you count Openstreetmap or a collection of several hundred topographic maps.  In some places they're well-mapped, e.g. when passing through Switzerland, Germany, or France, but in other countries they aren't, such as through Italy or Greece.

I'm sure there's plenty of traditional long-distance trails in Africa or Latin America that don't have accessible maps either.

I don't know if North America is any better.  Are there dedicated maps for the [Alexander MacKenzie Heritage Trail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_MacKenzie_Heritage_Trail)?  I've found that in North America, topographic maps often don't show the trails at all.  So there's certainly a market niche right there.

Except that almost nobody goes hiking there, so it certainly isn't profitable.  Which may just be why there aren't any maps available.

**Edit:** One *popular* trail that appears to not have any maps available (at least not in English) is [Jeju Olle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeju_Olle_Trail).  It's very scenic, not very remote, and attracts lots of hikers.  It appears that all hikers simply use a leaflet along with signposts.  Other trails in Korea might have the same pattern.  Topographic maps exist, but are *very* hard to obtain.

Answer (score 7):

The [Kungsleden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kungsleden) (lit. *kings way* in Swedish) is a 440 km long trail in northern Sweden/Scandinavia.

From Wiki:

> The trail is separated in four portions which each represent
>   approximately one week of hiking. The most practiced part is by far
>   the northernmost, between Abisko and Kebnekaise. The season, when the
>   huts are open usually runs between mid-June and the end of September,
>   rowing boats are usually at place in the end of June or beginning of
>   July.
>
> Huts have been constructed along the trail, separated by a distance
>   that a walker could expect to cover during the day, about 9-22
>   kilometres (6-14 mi). The huts are primarily operated by STF. For a
>   small fee, it is possible to pitch a tent outside and use the
>   facilities. Supplies can be bought in some of them (Alesjaure and
>   Kebnekaise Fjällstation for example). Some emergency shelters can also
>   be found on the route.

While there are the official Swedish maps, the only available scale I know of is 1:100'000 - quite large for hiking maps. On the other hand this also prevents the avid trekker to carry an entire backpack full of 1:25'000 maps.

Especially the northernmost section (1-2 weeks) is fairly popular, and there might be a fair demand for dedicated trail maps for this section. The guides that I own/saw personally only include very crude and essentially useless maps for tiny sections of the trail.

Apart from that it is also a wonderful trail. Highly recomend it. :)

Comment: Most of the northern part of Kungsleden is covered by [Norge-Serien](http://www.nordeca.com/kart/produkt_ns.php) (1:50,000).  In combination with the special [Kebnekaise map](http://www.kartbutiken.se/lantmateriets-kartor/fjallkartan/fjallkartan-150000/kebnekaise-hogfjallskarta) (1:20,000) that covers most or all of Dag Hammarskjöld-leden, although Kungsleden through Stuor Muorkke is not fully covered.  I've also seen dedicated Abisko Nationalpark maps, though very old. However, on a trail so clear and crowded in a landscape so open, a more detailed scale than 1:100,000 is hardly necessary.

Comment: Didn't know about the 1:50k, thx for mentioning it. And I agree mostly that the 1:100k is sufficient - the trail is exceptionally easy to find. Go off trail though (Sarek national park maybe?) and navigating gets a fair bit harder...

Comment: Off-trail is harder, but the OP is not proposing to prepare maps for off-trail use...